# Function template specialization format

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-specialization

What is the reason for the second brackets <> in the following function template:

```
template<> void doh::operator()<>(int i)
```

This came up in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937107/do-template-specializations-require-template-syntax) where it was suggested that there are brackets missing after `operator()`, however I could not find the explanation.

I understand the meaning if it was a type specialization (full specialization) of the form:

```
template< typename A > struct AA {};
template<> struct AA<int> {};         // hope this is correct, specialize for int
```

However for function templates:

```
template< typename A > void f( A );
template< typename A > void f( A* ); // overload of the above for pointers
template<> void f<int>(int);         // full specialization for int
```

Where does this fit into this scenarion?:

```
template<> void doh::operator()<>(bool b) {}
```

Example code that seems to work and does not give any warnings/error (gcc 3.3.3 used):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct doh
{
    void operator()(bool b)
    {
        cout << "operator()(bool b)" << endl;
    }

    template< typename T > void operator()(T t)
    {
        cout << "template <typename T> void operator()(T t)" << endl;
    }
};
// note can't specialize inline, have to declare outside of the class body
template<> void doh::operator()(int i)
{
    cout << "template <> void operator()(int i)" << endl;
}
template<> void doh::operator()(bool b)
{
    cout << "template <> void operator()(bool b)" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    doh d;
    int i;
    bool b;
    d(b);
    d(i);
}
```

Output:

```
operator()(bool b)
template <> void operator()(int i)
```

Comment: the above syntax of double parenthesis is very odd. Normally i have seen operator(bool b), but how does operator()(bool b) works? What is the use of first empty() ?

Comment: @Jimm the method name is `operator()` and it takes one parameter `bool b` ... it's the function call operator. See `main` in my code example, `d(b)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've looked it up, and found that it is specified by 14.5.2/2:

> A local class shall not have member templates. Access control rules (clause 11) apply to member template names. A destructor shall not be a member template. A normal (non-template) member function with a given name and type and a member function template of the same name, which could be used to generate a specialization of the same type, can both be declared in a class. When both exist, a use of that name and type refers to the non-template member unless an explicit template argument list is supplied.

And it provides an example:

```
template <class T> struct A {
    void f(int);
    template <class T2> void f(T2);
};

template <> void A<int>::f(int) { } // non-template member
template <> template <> void A<int>::f<>(int) { } // template member

int main()
{
    A<char> ac;
    ac.f(1); //non-template
    ac.f(’c’); //template
    ac.f<>(1); //template
}
```

Note that in Standard terms, `specialization` refers to the function you write using an explicit specialization and to the function generated using instantiation, in which case we have to do with a generated specialization. `specialization` does not only refer to functions you create using explicitly specializing a template, for which it is often only used.

Conclusion: GCC gets it wrong. Comeau, with which i also tested the code, gets it right and issues a diagnostic:

> `"ComeauTest.c"`, line 16: error: `"void doh::operator()(bool)"` is not an entity that
>             can be explicitly specialized
>     `template<> void doh::operator()(bool i)`

Note that it isn't complaining about the specialization of the template for `int` (only for `bool`), since it doesn't refer to the same name *and* type: The function type that specialization would have is `void(int)`, which is distinct from the function type of the non-template member function, which is `void(bool)`.

Comment: So if I follow correctly the 'template member' above is a templated member in "specialization of struct A for int". Make sense now, so calling ac.f() will do it's own template resolution based on the parameter or explicit template parameter list (whatever the correct name is).

Comment: yeah well the explicit specialization we provided for f is for the specialization of struct A for int. the general base template f exist for all specializations of A. That's why we can also call it on a A<char>, as it does in main, of course (but it won't use our explicit specialization, since that was only for A<int>::f<int>!) . Yeah ac.f(stuff) does its own resolution, indeed. Here, consult 14.8.1/2 ("Trailing template arguments that can be deduced..."). Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was just thinking that you could scare people by showing them this especially if they don't know c++ and templates syntax:  template <> template <> void A<int>::f<>(int) { }  or even better: template <> template <> void A<int>::operator()<>(int) { }

Comment: @stefanB, ahaha :P indeed, it looks suspicious. In any case, please bear with me - my last comment (now removed) said that for a primary (base) template definition, an explicit argument list shall be provided: Now getting up, i of course see that was nonsense all the way :)

Comment: In `template <> template <> void A<int>::f<>(int) { }`, isn't the `<>` just before the parameter list redundant? The compiler already knows you are referring to the template version of the member because of the `template <> template <>`.