# How to create and use a non type template in c++ and where would it be used

Tags: c++, templates

i am trying to learn templates in c++. Can someone please explain why sq() works and add() does not? How can add() be fixed? What is use of non type templates?

```
template <typename T>
inline T sq (const T& x) 
{
    return x*x;
}

template <int*>
inline int add(int* x)
{
   return (*x)*2;
}



int main() {
int x = 2;
cout<<"Square(2): "<<sq(2)<<" Add(2): "<<add(&x)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Even after modifying the above example as below, it would still Not work

```
template <typename T>
inline T sq (const T& x) 
{
    return x*x;
}

template <int>
inline int add(int x)
{
   return x+x;
}



int main() {
    cout<<"Square(2): "<<sq(2)<<" Add(2): "<<add(2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the exact purpose of add doesn't matter, as i mentioned above, it is just for learning. The fact is that add is valid from syntax perspective. My question is how to use it and why simple add(&x) wouldnt work ?

Comment: in this case, add(&x) _would_ work, which is why people are confused,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you could use a non-type template parameter to, for example, define a function template that adds any compile-time constant to its argument:

```
template <int N>
inline int add(int x)
{
    return x + N;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add<3>(2) << std::endl; // prints 5
    std::cout << add<4>(2) << std::endl; // prints 6
}
```

To answer your specific question about why `sq(2)` compiles but `add(&x)` doesn't: type parameters of function templates can be *deduced* from the function arguments. So `sq(2)` is equivalent to `sq<int>(2)`. Non-type parameters can't be deduced, so you have to provide one. In the case of a pointer parameter, the argument must be a pointer to a variable with external linkage, so the following should compile:

```
int global;

int main() {
    int local = 2;
    std::cout << add<&global>(&local) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, both int and pointers are "Non Type" parameters. But with sq(2), compiler is able to deduce from the argument, but not in case of pointers. You can declare add as template<int> inline int add(int x) {....} and it will still not work in as add(2)

Comment: @Jimm: `sq` has a type parameter (`typename T`); deduction from the function argument gives the type `int` for that parameter. `add` has a non-type parameter (`int*`), the value of which cannot be deduced.

Comment: In my modified example, the template for add should ONLY work for int. The syntax template<int> limits the choice to accepting arguments of type int. So there is no case left for deduction in case of this example....

Comment: You are right, if i modify add<2><9>, it works for my latter modified code in the question. But i am really confused, why compiler cannot deduce the type of parameter with non types, specially , when the declaration says template<int> ...

Comment: @Jimm: `template <int>` does not limit it to accepting arguments of type `int`; a normal function declaration `int add(int)` does that. `template <int> int add(int)` creates a function template with an integer template parameter, which is something quite different to a normal function.

Comment: @Jimm: Template arguments can only be deduced from the types of the arguments supplied to the function. Usually, this means that only type parameters can be deduced; but James Kanze's answer gives a (very useful) example of deducing an integer parameter: the integer forms part of the array's type, and so can be deduced from that.

Comment: The compiler will not let  you pass any other type than an int for a template<int> int add(int). If i pass say add<2.5>(2), the code will not compile. The only time code will compile successfully is, if i pass an integer argument to add, such as add<2>(9). template<T> T add(T x) allows different type of arguments, but template<int> int add(int x) limits you to strictly pass an integer argument.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6443/discussion-between-jimm-and-mike-seymour)

Answer (score 4):

The classical example of using a non-type template parameter for a 
function template would be something like:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T*
end( T (&array)[N] )
{
    return array + N;
}
```

In this case, if you write something like:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int* endPtr = end(a);
```

, the compiler can deduce the length of the array for you.

Comment: The syntax for end(T (&array)[N]) is very odd. For an array parameter to normal function, i would simply write it as end(int array[]) and the template equivalent then should be end(T arr[])

Comment: @Jimm The only way to pass a C style array to a function is by reference (as above).  `end(T array[N])` is the same as `end(T* array)`, which doesn't give argument deduction any means of determining the actual length (and doesn't give an error when passed a pointer).

Answer (score 2):

Your `add` function doesn't use any template-related features. It would work fine as a non-template function. I can't make out what you're really trying to do so unfortunately I can't even guess at a fix for your real problem.

EDIT: If from your title I infer you want to know about non-type template parameters, what about a totally incomplete array example:

```
template <typename T, int length>
struct Array
{
    T array_data_[length];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

As it was said, what you are trying to do is some how pointless, the only case when you might want to provide the exact parameter type in templates is for template functions overloading. for instance when you want to make some function work in different manner for some special type this is called template specialization. For more details you might want to visit
:
[Function template specialization format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937744/function-template-specialization-format)

Comment: Sounds like your taking about template specialization of template types.  Question is about non-type template _parameters_.

Comment: well yes the question is about non type param, however i was referring to the piece of code that is a mix of templates with directly define data types which for me sounds like template specialisation and since 'i am trying to learn templates in c++. ' i thought that this could be useful

Comment: For a template specialization, it would be `template <> inline int add<int*>(int* x)` which is different.  This code is _not_ specialization.

Answer (score -1):

The point of templates is that so you dont have to define a specific datatype in the function or class.
Look at `T add (const T& x)` . There is  no datatype in here, just a big `T` . That's due to that templates can assume the identity of any datatype, `int`, `double`, `char` or whatever you throw at it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
inline T sq (const T& x) 
{
    return x*x;
}

template <typename T>
inline T add (const T& x)
{
   return x+x;
}

template <typename T>
inline T divide (const T& x, const T& y)
{
   return x/y;
}


int main() 
{
    int x = 3;
    cout<<"int \n";
    cout<<"Square(3)    : "<<sq(x)<<" \n";
    cout<<"Add(3)       : "<<add(x)<<" \n";

    double y=3.00;
    cout<<"\ndouble \n";
    cout<<"Square(3)    : "<<sq(y)<<" \n";
    cout<<"Add(3)       : "<<add(y)<<" \n";

    double v=3.00;
    double w=2.00;
    cout<<"\ndouble \n";
    cout<<"Square(3)    : "<<sq(v)<<" \n";
    cout<<"Add(3)       : "<<add(v)<<" \n";
    cout<<"divide(3/2)  : "<<divide(v,w)<<" \n";
    cout<<"\n \n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's also non-type template parameters, used for other purposes.