# Template specialization of a member function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization, ofstream

I have to use an explicit specialization for a class member function in (C++ , I am using MS Visual Studio 2008 SP1), but I could not success to compile it. Getting

> error C2910: 'File::operator <<' : cannot be explicitly specialized

```
class File
{
   std::ofstream mOutPutFile;
public:
   template<typename T>
   File& operator<<(T const& data);
};


template<typename T>
File& File::operator<< (T const& data)
{
    mOutPutFile << preprosesor(data);
    return *this;
}

template< >
File& File::operator<< <> (std::ofstream& out)
{
   mOutPutFile << out;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%2B%2B%5D+specialize+member+function

Comment: You're working on Windows; the version of MSVC might be relevant.  It often helps people give better answers if you give that sort of information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function template specialization format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937744/function-template-specialization-format)

Comment: Your question is already answered by Andrey. On top of that you can think of having a *function overload* rather than *function specialization*. That will be simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your explicit specialization of operator << didn't match the parameter list of the declaration; `T const& data` vs `std::ofstream& out`.
This one compiles in MSVC10.

```
template<>
File& File::operator<< <std::ofstream> (const std::ofstream& out)
  {
  mOutPutFile << out;
  return *this;
  }
```

Notice `const` added before the function parameter.

Comment: Note that the ofstream here is an rvalue - it appears on the right side of << in usage.  When you define (global) operator<< the ostream must be non-const to actually compile.  That's not a problem here.

Comment: It's mOutPutFile, not std::ofstream& out, which is written to here.